# Core animation : Can you change the image during an animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I have some text which is an image. The image glows and sparkles etc over 10 frames(images).

I want to run some of the core animation tricks on this and have it grow in size and then fade. That works perfect when I just use the first image. But if i want to animate the image as the artist intended with its sparkles and glows I need to use all 10 frames(images) of the animation, so change the image during the animation. Is this possible? Are there any tricks to getting this to happen?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: try also animate layer's content property (which will be equal your images), not sure if the effect will be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to be able to perform multiple animations concurrently?

You can try using CAAnimationGroup.

Comment: Not really i think. I need to change the image thats being animated. I set an image as for the image property in an imageView. During the animation I want to change the image thats been show in the imageView. For example i have a blue ball being animated. Half way through the animation i want to remove the blue_ball_img.png and instead show red_ball_img.png.

Comment: AFAIK you can only animate what's shown here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html